# Is it more energy efficient to use cloud storage or connect a raspberry pi to an external hard disk? How can we quantify this?

Tags: thermodynamics

I am thinking about where to store my digital files for backup.
I want to have the lowest carbon footprint. 
(I'm going to use energy usage as a proxy for carbon emissions to make the problem simpler.)

I could use cloud storage such as Google One. https://one.google.com/about

I could connect a 4 TB external hard drive to a raspberry pi and connect it to the internet, making my own private version of the same thing.

https://medium.com/@aallan/adding-an-external-disk-to-a-raspberry-pi-and-sharing-it-over-the-network-5b321efce86a

Intuitively, I feel like using a google data center would be more more eco-friendly because of economies of scale.

How could I quantify this intuition?
Which solution is more energy efficient?
How much more energy efficient is it?

Comment: If you store your data on a cloud platform, you are paying them to protect it; they will use RAID, backups, etc, so your data is (hopefully) safe. If your 4TB external drive starts making funny clicking sounds, what are you going to do?

Comment: "The bottom line is that storing your data on the cloud uses far more energy than storing it on your computer" says [this article](https://medium.com/stanford-magazine/carbon-and-the-cloud-d6f481b79dfe)

Comment: But some cloud providers say they are carbon-neutral.

Comment: Commercial cloud products offer some degree of redundancy; a single-drive NAS does not. Also, that article you linked to is severely out of date. It refers to the Raspberry Pi 3, which has only USB 2 and 100 Mbit Ethernet. The Raspberry Pi 4 has USB 3 and gigabit Ethernet, and makes a much more capable NAS solution. I have one myself, and I use it for data backups, with a 2 TB external USB 3 drive. I can max out the Ethernet on my local LAN for reads and writes, but I do not use it as my only backup.